# Is the word 'Hitherto' outdated?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, adverbs

I am wondering if you would consider the word *hitherto* to be outdated. I prefer it over its definition, "until now" and know of no equal alternative. I have been marked down (on papers) for using this "archaic" word. So, is this word outdated? If so, what is a good alternative?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76013/discussion-on-question-by-quinn-is-the-word-hitherto-outdated).

Answer (score 68):

Merriam-Webster Unabridged *does not* flag *hitherto* as "archaic."

Macmillan does mark *[hitherto](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/hitherto)* as "very formal" but it's by no means outdated.

Whoever marked you down for using an "archaic" word is wrong (unless perhaps you were using *hitherto* in an informal context).

(Disclaimer: I read enough fantasy literature that *hitherto* seems rather ordinary to me.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76014/discussion-on-answer-by-gnawme-is-the-word-hitherto-outdated).

Answer (score 33):

Anecdotally, yes, I would consider it archaic, and if I heard you use it I'd either think you were being pretentious, or that you were deliberately joking about speaking in a pretentious manner.

For reference, I'm a college educated American in my 40s.

As for replacements, I would just use "up to now" or "up till now". "*yet*" also works in some contexts.

**Edit**: To further emphasize, despite my education and reasonably broad reading habits, I'm not sure that I could have correctly defined "hitherto" until encountering this question, so this is about more than just trying to avoid seeming old-fashioned. I think using this term outside of certain technical contexts means **you will not be widely understood by a general audience**.

Comment: ... as does "so far", again in the right contexts :)

Comment: @psmears Like in hitherto, hithergood

Comment: I agree.  I'm a college educated Brit in my *very* late 50's. (I only get to use that line for another week.)

Comment: pretentious ≠ archaic. And "excessively formal" / "unlikely to be understood" are not the same as "archaic" either.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR True, but pedantic. I'm answering OP's underlying question "should I refrain from using this word", and judging by the votes, others agree with me.

Comment: I'd say hitherto would appear pretentious in a speech in a colloquial context but written in an academic text, as in school, it's ordinary. Also, not wanting to be rude, if one doesn't know the definition of such a word - assuming a native English speaking adult - then I'd question if your education is as good as you imagine it to be. You're safe if you're not writing for children or tabloid press IMO.

Answer (score 23):

Though I agree with Gnawme's conclusion, I thought I'd check the Google Ngram viewer to see how "hitherto" compares with "until now" in terms of frequency of usage among their corpus of books in English over the years. [The chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hitherto%2Cuntil%20now&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chitherto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuntil%20now%3B%2Cc0) shows that the frequency of usage of "hitherto" fell fairly uniformly by 80-90% over the years from 1800 to 2000, with a slight upturn from 2000 to 2008.

Comment: The Google Books Ngram Viewer data sets from before 2000 and after 2000 are not directly comparable, so it is very common to find changes in trends *in the corpus* in the year 2000, but these may not always reflect actual changes in trends *in real usage*.  That's why the default window is set from 1800 to 2000, the most carefully curated portion of the corpus.  Please be careful what conclusions you draw if you decide to make charts from 1800 to 2008 with their tool.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Where is that documented? It certainly makes sense--I'd been wondering why they'd never updated the default, and I keep replacing it with 2008 because I thought it was desirable to have their most recent inclusions! Alas, they don't have *any* data after 2008.

Comment: Please see [the Supporting Online Material for *Quantitative Analysis of Culture Using Millions of Digitized Books* (2010)](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/early/2010/12/15/science.1199644/suppl/DC1).

Comment: Explained on page 12 of the PDF, thanks!

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hitherto%2Cuntil+now%2C+previously&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chitherto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuntil%20now%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpreviously%3B%2Cc0 "Previously" is most frequent than "hitherto" since 1840, but the latter seems far from archaïc. I'm surprised by the low occurence of "until now", though.

Comment: @Evargalo *I'm surprised by the low occurence of "until now", though* Yes! My thoughts exactly. This does not make sense. That hitherto is more popular today than "until now". The mind boggles.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I believe its because hitherto and previously are not quite the same as "until now" for example - "Bob had been a carpenter previously." "Bob had been a carpenter until now." These do not quite equate and the former is understandably more common.

Comment: @oMiKeY  I think I got it, the different word combinations with "hitherto" far outnumber that of  "until now" which is more limited. See: "hitherto unknown", "hitherto had", "hitherto been", "hitherto the", "hitherto in" etc. I can't post a link because  it has 1000's of characters!

Comment: I'd say hitherto is not as strict wrt time as "until now". Until now makes a very certain delineation whilst hitherto is looser: The "hitherto lost ruins" might have been found in the last few years, whilst "the ruins, lost until now" suggests a more recent find, to me at least. Also, no one has hitherto mentioned "formerly" as a synonym?

Answer (score 10):

Anecdotally, I read/hear the phrase "hitherto unknown" outside of legal or other technical contexts. I wouldn't say it's archaic, but it's not common. You could avoid it in favor of "previous(ly)" when speaking to a large or less-educated audience, but I don't see any reason to drop it from your vocabulary.

To expand on Green Grasso Holm's answer, here are some Ngrams comparing "hitherto", "until now", and "previously". It looks like "hitherto" is relatively more popular in British English, fiction, and phrases.

All English:
[image: English]

American English:
[image: American English]

British English:
[image: British English]

English Fiction:
[image: English Fiction]

"hitherto unknown" vs. "previously unknown":
[image: Phrases]

Comment: "prior to" appears to be more common than "until now" - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prior+to%2Cpreviously%2Chitherto&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprior%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpreviously%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chitherto%3B%2Cc0

Comment: "Prior to" doesn't mean the same thing, though. "Prior to now" is less common: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prior+to%2Cpreviously%2Chitherto%2C+prior+to+now&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprior%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpreviously%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chitherto%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprior%20to%20now%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Hitherto and previously do not have to refer to now though. Setting that reference point is what brings the occurrences down I believe.

Answer (score 5):

Extremely formal usage.  Many of the answers you received speak to the fact that 60%, 70%, 80%, 90% of the respondents have never heard it used (in spoken language) or have rarely (if ever) seen it used in written form.

Why use a word...when it's probable that 90% of your audience is totally unfamiliar with that word?

Everyone clearly understands what "until now" means.

Comment: _Why use a word...when it's probable that 90% of your audience is totally unfamiliar with that word?_ Maybe because it makes them look smarter?

Comment: _Why use a word..._ Here are some legitimate reasons. 1. Because it naturally reflects one's thinking process; 2. Because it is easier to say or sounds better in the sentence; 3. Because words with essentially the same meaning still vary in nuance and connotation; 4. Because it is extremely easy to find definitions of words these days and broad vocabulary is generally good for intellectual discussion; 5. To maintain a consistent tone. (Not that I advocate for using esoteric words. It depends on your aims and audience.)

Comment: I think it's actually rather unlikely that 90% of the audience is unfamiliar with the word *hitherto*.

Comment: Technically those are 5 "valid reasons".  Realistically...if you use the word "hitherto" in a conversation...you would confuse the vast majority of people  (regardless of the place/audience).  Anyone who was not confused would probably consider the usage "pretentious" (at best).

Answer (score 4):

I would tolerate *hitherto*, but I would consider the other words from this "set", *whitherto* and *thitherto*, to be archaic.  Similarly, *therefore* is fine, but *wherefore* and especially *herefore* can sound a bit outdated, though I think they sometimes make more sense in places we use *therefore*.  Just please use *therefor* correctly.

Comment: I think *wherefore* requires at least 10 minutes of lecture time to explain in every high school class that reads *Romeo and Juliet*. That's a good sign it's archaic.

Comment: Personally, I love _thitherto_ (though I don’t believe I’ve ever used _whitherto_). Conversely, I firmly hold that the only correct way to use _therefor_ is never, even more so with _wherefor_ and (eurgh!) _herefor_. @ThePhoton It’s a sad state of affairs if it takes a full ten minutes to explain to high school–aged people that _wherefore_ means _why_.

Answer (score 1):

It is, as Gnawme stated, entirely variable upon the environment in which the word is used or even if it manifests in discourse or written language. For legalese, the Law Dictionary defines *hitherto* as a 'restrict[ion] [of] the matter in connection with which it is employed to a period of time already passed.'

Therefore, although growing obsolescent in every-day language - Green Grasso presented an 80%-90% decrease between the 1800s and 2000 - it is nevertheless a plenteous lexeme in formal texts!

A similar set of adverbs, 'thereto' and the bygone phrase 'thereunto' might have undertaken a similar trajectory as hitherto, deemed literary or archaic words. This could be extrapolated to hitherto in the future.

Answer (score 0):

'Hitherto' is somewhat archaic, but still used, if largely just in legal writing.  It can mean 'up to now', or 'up to a specified time in the past' - i.e. 'up to then'.  If the archaic flavour upsets your professor use 'up to now' or 'up to then'.  We should always be aware of how what we write will be received by our audience!