# UK vs USA grammar, past tense usage of "were stood" and "found…stood" that jars my American mind

Tags: grammar, word-usage, american-english, british-english

One of my favorite authors uses past tenses in the following manner:

- *Other than Camden and Luke’s cousin Alex, who were stood outside the main doors talking, no one was in sight.*

  An American would write "... were standing..."
- *Stood in front of him, Tate folded his arms.*

  An American would say, "Standing in front..."
- *Khloé found herself stood in—ah, hell—a basement.*

  An American would use, "... standing in..."

Is this correct British grammar? Why the difference between regions?

I read sentences like these and my American brain stumbles and hiccups.

Comment: You don't fancy telling us who the author is? [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18609/is-i-am-sat-bad-english) is primarily about "am sat" but also mentions "were stood".

Comment: It almost seems like the UK usage is an example of the middle voice, or even a true deponent verb.  (Because, as the answers to the other question state, being "sat" somewhere doesn't have to imply someone else "sat" you there.)

Comment: Yes, the Brits use "were stood" for "were standing" and "were sat" for "were sitting". It is fine and it is standard in British English, I believe. Funny though for an AmE speaker. I am very surprised by what people say here because I see/hear these forms in series and movies **all the time**. Am I the only one watching British stuff and listening to the speakers?

Comment: That doesn't read like conventional UK English. I suspect that stood is used in the sense of "place." A teacher stood the student in the hallway when he wouldn't stop talking. The "were" is to make it passive.

Comment: It's misleading to present this as AmE and BrE "alternatives". The PP form is *extremely* informal / dialectal in BrE. But I also have the impression that Brits today are in general less concerned about "correct" grammar than Americans. It's probably relevant that British TV features ever more presenters with strong accents, and there been a *huge* increase in glottal stops from people telling us the news and weather, in recent years. They'd never have been hired at all a few decades ago, but nowadays, "ordinary people" are much sought after for such jobs.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ok, I said standard *but* it is extremely common in TV shows (police procedurals, for example) and movies. And one thing, FF, is for sure: AmE speakers don't use were sat and were stood over the ing forms  *at all*. Also, re accents, it was time for the British media (TV presenters especially) to get rid of posh, U accents-only presenters. Widening the choice of accents does not necessarily mean poorer grammar. I love all those accents on the BBC, it's charming.

Comment: (UK) A friend and I have a standing joke that when we hear someone say "I was sat [somewhere]", we both hear our late mothers say "_Sitting!_"

Comment: @KateBunting not a "stood joke", even now?

Comment: https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/ask_about_english/071231/ Read that blog post. Very good explanation of this: [...] you might be intrigued to learn that regional accents (although not dialects) have become very fashionable in broadcasting, but the announcers do read scripts written in standard English grammar! So good-bye and thank you for the question [...] /I was delighted to see that Brits use: I've went, just like Americans. Of course, very non standard in both!

Comment: As a BrE speaker, I would say "standing" for a person, but an object might be "stood in a corner" because it was placed there.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, that is standard for sure, I now know. BUT it is used colloquially all the time in the UK, as I have said because I have heard and hear it a lot in British movies and TV series. My mother (AmE) would correct me too: I have seen him recently, not I saw him recently. So, mothers can be good carriers of standard grammar.

Comment: @Lambie i don't think you should answer "Is this correct British grammar?" with "I hear it all the time colloquially."

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, look at the only answer so far. Just opinions from FF and Edwin.  *I did say that I now see it is not standard* but I still say that it is colloquial and very used. Are you Brits embarrassed by this usage? It would seem so. And FF talks about accents. This is not about accents; it's about class prejudice, isn't it?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/449476/is-have-went-gaining-common-currency-in-ame-and-bre

Comment: Problem word: **correct**. "Standard" is another matter!

Answer (score 3):

> It's misleading to present this as AmE and BrE "alternatives". The PP
> form is extremely informal / dialectal in 'BrE'. But I also have the
> impression that Brits today are in general less concerned about
> "correct" grammar than Americans. It's probably relevant that British
> TV features ever more presenters with strong accents, and there [has]
> been a huge increase in glottal stops from people telling us the news
> and weather, in recent years. They'd never have been hired at all a
> few decades ago, but nowadays, "ordinary people" are much sought after
> for such jobs.

–   FumbleFingers [minor adjustments]

As for English considered standard in the UK, the [Guardian Style Guide](https://mistakeswritersmake.com/sat-and-sitting-stood-and-standing-mistakes-115-and-116/) has:

> We stand for 'standing' and 'sitting' [in such usages] but we will not
> stand for 'stood' and 'sat'.

So 'Yes, the Brits use "were stood" for "were standing" and "were sat" for "were sitting" ' is a gross overgeneralisation, and 'It is fine and it is standard in British English' just plain wrong.

Comment: https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/ask_about_english/071231/ Teachers correct it but people say it. It is heard all the time on British series and in British movies. It is not an overgeneralization. It's the vox populi. The Guardian has a style guide but the BBC blog post explains its usage. And does not condemn it. Do you think I have bad hearing?

Comment: And this long article: https://random-idea-english.blogspot.com/2013/11/random-thoughts-he-was-sat-she-was-stood.html "But I have to say that personally I find them rather attractive and, like a lot of idiomatic English, an enrichment of the language.
The main thing is that when you hear a native speaker say it, don't think they are making an error or are grammatically ignorant: **this is a perfectly natural British English expression, albeit one that is not accepted in all quarters**."

Comment: ['In an Oct. 3, 2012, post on the Oxford Dictionaries blog, the lexicographer Catherine Soames notes the increasing nonstandard use of the past participles “sat” and “stood” for the present participles “sitting” and “standing” in British English.' ... Soames, editor or co-editor of several Oxford dictionaries, says [this usage] in continuous, or progressive, tenses is “regarded as non-standard by usage guides.” '](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2017/12/sat-stood.html#:~:text=Soames%2C%20editor%20or%20co%2Deditor,%2Dstandard%20by%20usage%20guides.%E2%80%9D).

Comment: She also says:  “The answer’s not clear,” Soames says, “but my research shows that this usage (which used to be restricted to some regional British dialects) **is becoming more widespread in British English**, and is even appearing in edited writing such as newspapers and magazines.”

Comment: @Lambie It is still termed 'nonstandard' in the article.

Comment: In the (UK) Guardian, 2nd February 2024, a prosecutor in a London court said, “Miss [Greta] Thunberg was stood outside the hotel entrance.”

Comment: ... and in the same article: 'Giving evidence, Sgt Tony Sothinathan of the Met police said Thunberg was standing near to the entrance of the InterContinental Hotel'.  The police often find lawyers' words somewhat bewildering.

Answer (score 0):

I would understand "he was stood" to indicate there was some decision or compulsion about where he was standing.

"They were stood outside" is a passive voice version of "Somebody or something stood them outside". To "stand somebody" indicates a degree of compulsion, in the same way as to "place somebody" does. Somebody could stand themselves in a place; in that case it would be decision rather than compulsion. "I stood myself in the classroom corner, where I could see all the students"

Coming out of this understanding I would understand the three example sentences to be saying more than if they had used "were standing". The first suggests that Camden and Alex had deliberately selected their position (they had stood themselves there). The other two suggest to me that some other agent, fate, or a series of events, had placed Tate and Khloe in their locations.

Understood in this way the sentences are not ungrammatical, and are not necessarily erroneous.